# Combining Python Pandas Dataframe outputs from program Into One Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

After several weeks of refining this I have the following code thanks to awesome folks on SO which produces dataframes as I need but I'm not sure how to concat the dataframes in the program into one for the final dataframe object variable. I just assign the concat statement to a variable then I end up getting the last dataframe only.

```
{
"zipcode":"08989",
"current" {"canwc":null,"cig":4900,"class":"observation","clds":"OVC","day_ind":"D","dewpt":19,"expireTimeGMT":1385486700,"feels_like":34,"gust":null,"hi":37,"humidex":null,"icon_code":26,"icon_extd":2600,"max_temp":37,"wxMan":"wx1111"},
"triggers":[53,31,9,21,48,7,40,178,55,179,176,26,103,175,33,51,20,57,112,30,50,113]
}
{
"zipcode":"08990",
"current":{"canwc":null,"cig":4900,"class":"observation","clds":"OVC","day_ind":"D","dewpt":19,"expireTimeGMT":1385486700,"feels_like":34,"gust":null,"hi":37,"humidex":null,"icon_code":26,"icon_extd":2600,"max_temp":37, "wxMan":"wx1111"},
"triggers":[53,31,9,21,48,7,40,178,55,179,176,26,103,175,33,51,20,57,112,30,50,113]
}

def lines_per_n(f, n):
    for line in f:
        yield ''.join(chain([line], itertools.islice(f, n - 1)))

def series_chunk(chunk):
    try:
        jfile = json.loads(chunk)
        zipcode = jfile['zipcode']
        datetime = jfile['current']['proc_time']
        triggers = jfile['triggers']
        return pd.Series([jfile['zipcode'], jfile['current']['proc_time'],\
                            jfile['triggers']])
    except ValueError, e:
        pass
    else:
        pass

for fin in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fin) as f:
        print pd.concat([series_chunk(chunk) for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 5)], axis=1).T
```

output from above program which I need to concat as one dataframe:

```
       0               1                                                  2
0  08988  20131126102946                                                 []
1  08989  20131126102946  [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179, 176, ...
       0               1                                                  2
0  08988  20131126102946                                                 []
1  08989  20131126102946  [53, 31, 9, 21, 48, 7, 40, 178, 55, 179, 176, ...
```

Finally wrestled this into submission. Here is final code that does what I need:

```
dfs = []
for fin in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(fin) as f:
        df = pd.concat([series_chunk(chunk) for\
            chunk in lines_per_n(f, 7)], axis=1).T
        dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#concatenating-objects; just append the df's to a list, them to a list, then concat at the end, e.g. ``result = pd.concat([list_of_frames])``

Comment: you might be able to do some of this directly via: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#json (their is also a Normalization section available in 0.13 for nested json)

Comment: @Jeff I tried doing this and got `ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.`, :S

Comment: @AndyHayden never used the normalization myself...

Comment: @Jeff I'd not seen it was implemented! Think there are some codes I can make less messy. Syntax looks magical.

Comment: I suspect it's pretty slow too; could be pretty useful for nested parsing

Answer (score 1):

Glad you got this sorted. IMO a slightly cleaner way to do this as a list comprehension

```
def dataframe_from_file(fin):
    with open(fin) as f:
        return pd.concat([series_chunk(chunk) for chunk in lines_per_n(f, 7)],
                            axis=1).T

df = pd.concat([dataframe_from_file(fin) for fin in glob.glob('*.txt')],
                  ignore_index=True)
```

*Note: it could be that using axis=1 to the final concat means you can avoid T-ing earlier.*

Comment: definitely cleaner. Thank you.